# how to determine if a socket handle is ipv4 or ipv6?

Tags: sockets

Given a socket handle, is there any way to determine if it is AF_INET or AF_INET6, e.g. first parameter to create socket(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket)? I am programming on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getsockopt` function:

```
int getsockopt(
  [in]      SOCKET s,
  [in]      int    level,
  [in]      int    optname,
  [out]     char   *optval,
  [in, out] int    *optlen
);
```

If `optname` parameter is `SO_PROTOCOL_INFO`, buffer should contain `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` structure. It's `iAddressFamily` member will be `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`.

[getsockopt function (winsock.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt)

[WSAPROTOCOL_INFOA structure (winsock2.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/ns-winsock2-wsaprotocol_infoa)

Comment: that's it, thanks